# Binding not working when using separate controller

Tags: visual-studio-2010, angularjs

I've just started using angular.js and was going through the tutorials till I hit a bump.
I'm making a simple app which takes in 2 inputs and shows the product of those 2 values (using visual studio 2010). It works nicely when I don't use a separate controller like so

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
        <table data-ng-init="quant=1;price=2;curr=['e','u','r'];">
            <tr>
            <td>Quantity:</td>
            <td><input type="number" ID="text_quantity" data-ng-model="quant" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Price:</td>
            <td><input type="number" ID="text_price" data-ng-model="price" />
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Total:</td>
            <td>{{quant*price | currency}}</td>
           </tr>
     </table>
     <span ng-repeat="c in curr" ng-bind="c"></span>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But when i try to use controller the binding expression "{{quant*price | currency}}" stops working and instead of product of 2 values the expression itself i.e "{{quant*price | currency}}" appears in the page. Below is the code written for separate controller:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="invoice1">
<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/invoice1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
    Quantity: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs: <input type="number" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
    <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
      <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Total:</b>
    <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
      {{invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
    </span>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller(Invoice1.js):

```
angular.module('invoice1', [])
.controller('InvoiceController', function() {
this.qty = 1;
this.cost = 2;
this.inCurr = 'EUR';
this.currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
this.usdToForeignRates = {
  USD: 1,
  EUR: 0.74,
  CNY: 6.09
};

this.total = function total(outCurr) {
  return this.convertCurrency(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
};
this.convertCurrency = function convertCurrency(amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
  return amount * this.usdToForeignRates[outCurr] * 1 / this.usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
};
this.pay = function pay() {
  window.alert("Thanks!");
};
});
```

Kindly help in this regard.

Comment: I tried the code and it seems to work fine. Have you forgotten to load Invoice1.js? Check what errors you get in the browsers developer console.

Comment: no I did include invoice1.js...just double checked it..can it be cuz im doing this on visual studio 2010..although it seems pretty unlikely even to me.

Comment: @tasseKATT it was working? how??

Comment: His code: http://plnkr.co/edit/vVa5MEEAWTCQukJCt2mI?p=preview

Comment: Please make sure all your divs are properly closed, or post your entire html.

Comment: what version of angular do you use?

Comment: Make sure you are using Angular 1.2 since the "Controller as"-syntax was not available in earlier versions.

Comment: im using 1.2.1 version

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser developer console?

Comment: used firebug in firefox and developer console in chrome it appears as though controller isn't being  called at all....(used debugger)

Comment: @Arawn do you get any errors in the console? (if so show them) if not 99% your script is not being loaded (so check you server-side)...

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting this behavior as well, will report back once I identify what might be happening.

Comment: I have my custom script after the angular.js file and I'm getting this:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module invoice1 due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'invoice1' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.